# Is there any Github Flavored Markdown library in Go?

Tags: go, r-markdown

I know Blackfriday is awesome, but it still doesn't fully support GFM. Are there any other viable libraries?

Comment: Not sure if it supports all of GFM, but you could try Knieriem's markdown library (https://github.com/knieriem/markdown) .